# Can Trello Webhooks be dynamically registered in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, trello

I am constructing a web app in Google Apps Script that updates a card in Trello when a checkbox is checked on a different card.  My question is, if along with this functionality, I also wanted to construct a new card with a checkbox that performs the same function, is this possible with Google Apps Script?  This would require (I think) registering a new webhook dynamically to the new card.

Currently I am using http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/pimp-your-trello-cards as a tutorial.  He states this cannot be done as the web app must be deployed with the settings of:

- Execute the app as: User accessing the web app
- Who has access to the app: Anyone

to register the webhooks because Trello sends back a HEAD request to complete the handshake. And the app must be updated as:

- Execute the app as: Me
- Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous

to receive POST responses from the webhooks.  If this is the case then I don't think I can do what I want as I need to toggle the permissions each time the webhooks are registered.  I have attempted using each set of permissions for both registering the webhooks and receiving the POST responses but either the hooks will not register or the responses will not be received.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not change the permissions of Google Apps Script programmatically.**

[Alternative solutions]

1. **If idModel of webhook is set to idMember instead of card id, all actions can be received comprehensively. You can combine Label and action type to create the function you want.**
2. *Use a Google Cloud Functions (GCF) paid plan.
   GCF can use res.status (200) so you do not need to change permissions.
   GCF Spark Plan (Free Plan)'s outbound networking
   is restricted to Google services only. That is, you can receive Webhook from Trello but can not send a request to Trello.
   In case of Flame Plan ($ 25 / month), you can receive a webhook  and set a webhook on another card with one function.*
3. *If you do not use webhook any more with the registered card, there is a way to update idModel with the id of the next card.*